# Aiming Ki with tensorflow.js

Tags: neural-network, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I created a little game with p5js. In the game there is a ball which can be shot in an adjustable angel and power. The ball has to hit a target which has an random distance and height.

Now I want to build a Neuralnetwork with tensorflow.js which always hits the target. I know that this probleme can be solved by a simple algorithm but I want to learn tensorflow.js.

To train my model I created an dataset with 10000 entries. It consists of the distance and the height if the target and the values of power and angel to hit it. Than I used the model setup from Daniel shiffmanns color classifier and adjusted the inputs and outputs for my purpose. I maped the output onto the angel and power.
Than I trained it. But the loss didnt  decrease.

After a bit of research I found out that the outputs add up to 1, therfore it makes no sence to use the normalized output and map it onto the distance and angel.

Now my questions are:
How can i get the angel and power from the output?
How many layers shoud it have?
Which activation and loss functions should I use?
Or is thevprobleme to complex for my first atempt with tensorflow.js?

I hope I described it clear.

**Edit**

I realised that my biggest probleme is the outputfunction. Can somebody give me a clue which I should use or how I can design one? I dont find anything to this topic on the tensorflow.js website

Comment: Such questions are highly dependent on the problem and the goal you want to achieve. Generally there is no perfect model for any given task. Your problem can be solved by a simple equation and thus the model could be quite simple.

Comment: Okay but how should I design it? I am completly new to this topic and it would be very helpfull if somebody can give me a tip on how to design the model

Comment: You have 2 inputs (x,y) and 2 outputs (angle, strength). Start with one dense layer and keep experimenting until you get the desired outcome.

Comment: Yeah I know but before I start I have to know how I can map the outputs to the angel and the power. I cant take the probability as an result or? Should I make 100 outputs (90 for every degree and 10 for the power) and how can I get two seperate propabilities?

Comment: Use an independent output-function and just use their values.

Comment: As I said I am completele new to the topic. Can you give me a clue how it would look or link an article which describes this

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide has a lot of code you can look at.